# Why Can't I Change My Skin in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a premium account, but I can't change my skin. This error keeps popping up every time I try. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

[image: Minecraft Skin Error]

Comment: It says no file chosen. Did you choose a file to upload?

Comment: The error comes after I upload a file.

Comment: Is it a PNG?  Is it the right size?

Comment: I'm having that problem too. Tried uploading a .png that I know has worked before and it gave the same error. I'm thinking it's the site itself that's messed up and not anything either of us is doing.

Comment: It's one of the top skins on planetminecraft.com. It's most likely the right-sized skin then, since no one else has reported problems with it and I haven't messed around with it. It is a PNG as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your skin isn't on Planet Minecraft you can use the remote uploader to change your skin.

First make sure you're signed in to minecraft.net, then upload the skin you want to an image hosting site like tinypic.com, for example. Then copy the direct url for your image.

Paste the direct url for your skin after the = in this address:

> http://www.minecraft.net/skin/remote.jsp?url=

You should get a URL that looks something like this:

> http://www.minecraft.net/skin/remote.jsp?url=http://i52.tinypic.com/ehahel.png

You should get a page that will ask you to confirm your skin change. Select 'Yes' and it should send you back to your Minecraft profile page with a message that the change was successful.

It's a bit of a workaround but the page should be fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

If it comes from planetminecraft why don't you use the "Change my skin" button on the skin page?

[image]

Then you'll be transfered to minecraft.net and enter your user / password to accept the change and voila!